# SetValue for BindableProperty doesn't trigger PropertyChanged event when set to null

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

in a Xamarin.Forms project i develop, i created a NullableDatePicker which works with a DateTime? value. Until XF 3.3 the DatePicker was able to set the DateTime? property of the ViewModel to null. This no longer works with XF 3.5 Now when my platformrenderer sets the BindableProperty of the XF Control to null, the bound property of the viewmodel isn't updated. Changing the value to a DateTime works.

As searching through the changes between XF 3.3 and the current XF 3.5 didn't brought any breaking changes for the binding to light, i hope someone here on stackoverflow can help. I already searched quite a lot for a possible cause of my problem.

```
public class ViewModel {
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date{
        get => _date;
        set => SetProperty(ref _date, value);
    }
}

NullableDatePicker : DatePicker {
    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(NullableDatePicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

public class DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class NullableDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    ...
    public void OnClearDateTimeSelection(){
        ((IElementController) Element).SetValueFromRenderer(NullableDatePicker.NullableDateProperty, null);
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, I will check it for you.^.^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating from 3.4.0.1008975 to 3.5.X. I didn't find the reason of that yet, but I also didn't need the update, and that's what I recommend to you.

Version 3.5.X basically add bindable layouts to XF. If you don't need it, I recommend you to downgrade to 3.4.0.1008975 that it'll work.